# Interpretations of (pseudo)hallucinations vis a vis the Talmud’s interpretations of dreams

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, talmud-gemara, theology, dream, ruach-hakodesh

The Talmud (last chapter of Berachot, 55a ff.) contains a long treatment interpreting various visions one may experience “בחלום” (in a dream).

If when under the influence of a psychoactive drug an individual sees visions described in the Talmud, would such visions also be open to the respective interpretations offered by the rabbis of Talmud? By extension, concerning various characterizations of dreams by the Talmud (some collected [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10504/15571)), is all related discussion limited specifically to dreams induced by sleep? In other words, is it limited to a naturally altered state of consciousness or would an induced altered state of consciousness likewise be included?

Unlike [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77969/15571) question about lucid dreams, many people can have no recollection of their “dreams” while under the influence of psychoactive drugs and therefore such a state of consciousness wouldn’t be comparable to lucid dreaming and, instead, more akin to actual sleep.

Comment: Narcoanalysis was a trend before some decades. From svara, there are dreams 100%. Not hallucinations. Hallucinations are generally with not altered consciousness. There are drugs that make hallucinations and there are drugs that clearly alter consciousness. There are  intermediary states, stuporous. Psychosis (alteration of reality testing) content of thought are close to dreams from a psychanalytic point of view. But regarding Gemara, it's not obvious what's the point. Shotim have a nevua equivalent power. Gemara speaks about substance induced psychosis as kordiakus, effect of wine מגיתו